# Flux through conducting surfaces

Tags: electric-fields

I had a doubt regarding electric flux.Can electrix flux be defined through conducting surfaces as no electric fields lines pass through the conductor ?. Or is it that we only consider electric field lines that strike the surface normally and not actually pass through the surface?

Comment: A conductor would rearrange charges within it self so that electric field inside becomes 0 (because if not charges flow and ultimately lead to this). Flux - field lines through a body, meaning fields lines enter it. But since charges are rearranging so that no lines through it all lines either terminate or are parallel to surface and none enter the body. Thus no flux.

Comment: realistically, there will be some flux initially before rearranging completes but then at steady state, 0

Comment: Could you tell me what kind of surfaces can be considered for calculating flux ?

Comment: what do you mean? Gaussian surfaces? those are imaginary, you dont really decide material of it. Conductors have 0 flux because they modify fields in space once they are placed there (by rearraangement in themselves)

Comment: I meant like can we calculate Flux through insulating surfaces etc. ?